# Replace one column with another except another is NaN in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Assuming the test dataset as follows:

```
   id   name1  name2
0   1   james  James
1   2    Bond    NaN
2   3  Steven    NaN
3   4     Tom  Kevin
4   5    Alba    Tim
```

How could I replace `name1`'s values with `name2`, except `name2` are `NaN`?

The expected result:

```
   id   name1  name2
0   1   James  James
1   2    Bond    NaN
2   3  Steven    NaN
3   4   Kevin  Kevin
4   5     Tim    Tim
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible replace `name2` misisng values by `name1` and assign to `name1`:

```
df['name1'] = df['name2'].fillna(df['name1'])
print (df)
   id   name1  name2
0   1   James  James
1   2    Bond    NaN
2   3  Steven    NaN
3   4   Kevin  Kevin
4   5     Tim    Tim
```

Or you can use some solution with test missing/ non missing values, e.g. here [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['name1'] = df['name1'].mask(df['name2'].notna(), df['name2'])
print (df)
   id   name1  name2
0   1   James  James
1   2    Bond    NaN
2   3  Steven    NaN
3   4   Kevin  Kevin
4   5     Tim    Tim
```

**Sample**:

```
temp="""   id   name1  name2
0   1   james  James
1   2    Bond    NaN
2   3  Steven    NaN
3   4     Tom  Kevin
4   5    Alba    Tim"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep="\s+")
    
print (df)
   id   name1  name2
0   1   james  James
1   2    Bond    NaN
2   3  Steven    NaN
3   4     Tom  Kevin
4   5    Alba    Tim
```

Comment: BTW, how could I read my test data in question? Should I use `pd.read_fwf(StringIO('''  '''))` or other functions?

Comment: @ahbon - I think `read_csv` is better here

Answer (score 3):

```py
df.name1 = np.where(df.name2.isna(), df.name1, df.name2)
```

Here the complete code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [
        ['James',  'James'],
        ['Bond', np.nan],
        ['Steven', np.nan],
        ['Tom', 'Kevin'],
        ['Alba', 'Tim',],
    ], columns =['name1', 'name2']
)

df.name1 = np.where(df.name2.isna(), df.name1, df.name2)
```

The result is:

```sh
    name1  name2
0   James  James
1    Bond    NaN
2  Steven    NaN
3   Kevin  Kevin
4     Tim    Tim
```